# tokenizer has no attribute oov_token

Tags: keras

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dac.py", line 87, in 
    X_train=load_create_padded_data(X_train=X_train,savetokenizer=False,isPaddingDone=False,maxlen=sequence_length,tokenizer_path='./New_Tokenizer.tkn')
  File "/home/dpk/Downloads/DAC/New_Utils.py", line 92, in load_create_padded_data
    X_train=tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X_train)
  File "/home/dpk/anaconda2/envs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/text.py", line 278, in texts_to_sequences
    return list(self.texts_to_sequences_generator(texts))
  File "/home/dpk/anaconda2/envs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/text.py", line 296, in texts_to_sequences_generator
    oov_token_index = self.word_index.get(self.oov_token)
AttributeError: 'Tokenizer' object has no attribute 'oov_token'

Answer (score 1):

Probably this one:

> You can manually set tokenizer.oov_token = None to fix this.
>
> Pickle is not a reliable way to serialize objects since it assumes
>   that the underlying Python code/modules you're importing have not
>   changed. In general, DO NOT use pickled objects with a different
>   version of the library than what was used at pickling time. That's not
>   a Keras issue, it's a generic Python/Pickle

https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/9099

Answer (score 0):

To fix this I manually set

```py
self.oov_token = None
```

But not

```py
tokenizer.oov_token = None
```